# Calling performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone: more than once on same thread results in delay

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

For code like:

```
// Code in some object that will do work for an application:  

- (BOOL)shouldBeRunning  
{  
  [lockRunning lock];  
  BOOL shouldBeRunning= shouldRun;  
  [lockRunning unlock];  

  return shouldBeRunning;  
}  

- (void)stopRunning  
{  
  [lockRunning lock];  
  shouldRun= FALSE;  
  [lockRunning unlock];  
}  

- (void)threadEntryPoint:(id)object  
{  
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];  

  NSRunLoop *runLoop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];  

  // From an example I saw awhile back:  
  // A runloop with no sources returns immediately from runMode:beforeDate:  
  // That will wake up the loop and chew CPU. Add a dummy source to prevent it.  
  NSMachPort *dummyPort = [[NSMachPort alloc] init];  
  [runLoop addPort:dummyPort forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];  
  [dummyPort release];  
  [pool release];  

  while ([self shouldBeRunning])   
  {  
    NSAutoreleasePool *loopPool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];  
    [runLoop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];  
    [loopPool drain];  
  }   
}  

- (BOOL)startRunning:(NSError **)errorPtr  
{  
  [self stopRunning];  // Stop if we are already running.  

  [runWorker release];  
  runWorker= [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(threadEntryPoint:) object:nil];  

  if(!runWorker)  
    return (FALSE);  

  // Start up the thread.  
  shouldRun= TRUE;  

  [runWorker start];  

  return TRUE;  
}  

- (void)doLotsOfStuff  
{  
  // Some operation that is long and intensive  
  // that should be done in the background.  
  // This function will call the app delegate, which will display the  
  // results. It will also notify the app on completion.  
}    

- (void)doStuff
{  
  // Commented out for illustrative purposes.  
  //[self startRunning];  // Fire thread up.  

  [self performSelector:@selector(doLotsOfStuff) onThread:runWorker withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];  
}    

// Out in the delegate:  
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification*)aNotification  
{  
  // Do setup....  
  [workObject startRunning];  // Start the worker thread in the worker object.  
}  

- (void)buttonHandler:(id)sender  
{  
  [workObject doStuff];  
}
```

So, in the application there is a button. The user will press it, and a task will run on a worker thread. The task will provide feedback to the application. In this case, the button is disabled until the task completes. I just do not want to show all that code.

With the code as written, if I press the button once, the task runs without delay. Often, a second button press yields the same result. However, sometimes the second press, but almost always the third or after, will result in a significant delay in performing the task. I put debug statements in and can observe that the code does the performSelector on the thread, then there is a delay, and finally the task runs.

If I uncomment the line in doStuff that re-creates the thread (making the one in applicationDidFinishLaunching redundant), of course it works perfectly every time.

From what I can tell, the thread is getting into an unresponsive state.

Any ideas on what might be going on? Anything obviously wrong with the setup and handling code? Any input appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at NSOperationQueue? maybe this is a better solution for what you need. you could run the queue on the background thread. There is a good tutorial here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues

Comment: I haven't seen code like this in a long time. Is there a reason you've not updated to [dispatch_async()](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_async)?

Comment: Seemingly good reasons to not fully embrace GCD: This code is a super stripped example. I am performing open-ended asynchronous I/O on multiple chips with a high polling frequency. Once the communication channel(s) gets set up a user can acquire data indefinitely, so the receive thread could run a long time. A given simple operation might involve a series of read/write operations on a chip; depending on the response, more read/write operations - unknown in number until the connection is initiated. The code generally works well as is. Just noticed a delay when a specific operation is repeated.

Comment: Also, when I started the project, there was no GCD....